# Where can I find sold item notes in the Square API?

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to create a report to pull my Square POS transaction data into Excel through Power Query. Basically, I want the information available in the standard "Items Detail CSV" report found in the Square Dashboard, but connected to Excel so I can build custom reporting and update it any time with a refresh.

I can connect to the Square data in Excel no problem. What I'm having trouble with is finding the right data, specifically the notes the merchant can enter in during the time of sale about the item. We have several items that will come up as "Custom Amount" where we enter additional notes about the item, and I can't find the notes field through the API.

After looking through the documentation, I've tried two main queries:

1. The Transactions List from v2:
   https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/{location_id}/transactions
2. The Payments List from v1:
   https://connect.squareup.com/v1/{location_id}/payments

The Payments List includes the v1PaymentItemization data type, which should include the notes field defined as "Notes entered by the merchant about the item at the time of payment, if any." I assume that's what I'm looking for.

(Link to documentation: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#type-v1paymentitemization)

However, I cannot find the notes field anywhere in my pulled results. There are no error messages, and I see every data field listed in the v1PaymentItemization documentation except "notes" in my query results.

Edit: The notes we're using are on individual items, not the payment as a whole. This fits the description of V1 List Payments -> PaymentItemization -> notes. I did check the tender notes as mentioned in the comments, but this was not what I'm looking for. Until now, I wasn't aware we could make a comment on the transaction as a whole, as opposed to individual items. The individual items notes would be more helpful anyway.

Either way, I didn't find the tender notes in the pulled data either. Most of the fields are there in the data pull, but not notes, v1TenderEntryMethod, and a couple of others. There's actually more data available in the standard dashboard reports than is actually pulling from the API.

I do realize a workaround is to export the Item Detail CSV report from the Square Dashboard, and then manipulate the data in Excel from there. I could even have a connection to the folder or file where I save my exports. It's just not as smooth as the desired result of opening Excel, setting my parameters there, and clicking refresh to get the data and formatted report all in one place.

Thanks

Second Edit: In the POS, I'm entering an amount which shows up as Custom Amount in the itemized list for the sale. I then click on the Custom Amount to add a note to it and specify what the item is (e.g., "Lamp"). That note is applied to a single item, and there may be several items per transaction that have these notes added to them which would otherwise only show as "Custom Amount" on a report or receipt. We do this because we sell several items that are not standard inventory items, but we do want to keep track of what we've sold.

I can see these notes for each item in the standard reporting, so I know the data is entered and saved correctly. However, I can't find the note field when I pull from the API. I see all of the other itemization fields (i.e., name, quantity, item_detail, itemization_type, etc.), but not the note field.

I'm getting these results with a simple /v1/payments pull with no parameters or filters.

Comment: Are you adding notes to individual items, or the overall payment? If the latter, then I believe you should be looking at the V1 List Payments -> `tenders` -> `payment_note` (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-v1tender)

Comment: Updated the original post to address comments. Thanks

Comment: So, just to be super clear, in the POS you're entering an amount, clicking on "Current Sale", then clicking the "Custom Amount" and adding a note? I just tested this and it does indeed show up in `V1 Payment` > `itemizations` > `notes`. If you're adding notes this way and not seeing them, then I'll need more information. Please reach out to our support team via: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/contact?panel=BF53A9C8EF68 and mention this thread.

Comment: Added clarification

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Based on your second edit it does sound like you should be seeing these notes. Do you mind reaching out to our API support team (provided in the last comment) so that we can take a look at your account and logs to see what might be going wrong?